# Finding transformation matrix, given two sets of plane parameters and points on each plane

Tags: matlab, math, transformation, plane

**Problem:**

I have a set of planes in 3d. I represent them using the following information

1. plane equation : Ax + By + Cz + D = 0; (I have the coefficients in a vector)
2. points from which the plane_param A,B,C,D were found (using least squares)

An array of structures, named `frame1[]` is used to store this information. `frame1[1]` represents first plane. It has the following members, `frame[1].plane_param` (1 x 4 vector) and `frame1[1].points` (3 X N matrix for N points)

Now I have another set of planes in an array of structures, named `frame2[]`. This set will contain at least 5 planes planes that are present in `frame1[]`. array index wise, they will not have one to one correspondence. In other words, `frame1[1]` and `frame2[1]` may represent different planes.

**What I need:**

A method by which I will be able to get a single homogeneous transformation [4x4] that would transform all the planes in `frame2[]` to `frame1[]`. I do understand that the answer will have errors. In other words a perfect transformation matrix may not exist, in that case a transformation matrix that best suits the data (in a least squares sense) is enough.

**Constraints:** 
The rotation angles are very small. if the exact angles are not possible to deduce, an approximation like `cos(alpha) = 1` and `sin(alpha) = alpha` can be used in the transformation matrix.

**Language:** MATLAB

Comment: It is indeed true that you can transform one plane to another by 4x4 matrix. But how do you define the "error", or the "distance" between two planes?

Comment: @ysakamoto By "error" I just meant the approximation of angles. "distance" between two planes is zero, unless they are parallel. I agree. But then, Think of this like a rigid body, rather than a plane. We know the CG of the body (which is given by the points), we know the normal to the surface of the plane (given by the plane parameters, I assume, please correct me if i am wrong). So the 4x4 should have the rotation information and the translation of the CG. this translation is what i termed as "distance"

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to transform 5 planes to 1 plane using only one 4x4 transformation matrix? Each plane needs a unique transformation. So if you only use one transformation, you will not get the right plane after the transformation. I thought that is what you call the "error".

Comment: @ysakamoto, sorry if my language confuses you. I have two sets of 5 planes. I want to find a single transformation matrix can transform one set to another.

Comment: yes. so if you use a single transformation matrix to transform 5 planes to other 5 planes, then you cant do it exactly because one transformation matrix is only good for one plane. Then I think you need to find the transformation matrix that minimize the error, but you need to define how to compute the "error".

Comment: @ysakamoto I dont have very much idea on that. my current approach is like this: The difference between the norms might be a good param for error. As in let [A B C D] be the param of a plane in set 1 and [A1 B1 C1 D1] of a plane in set 2. If [A' B' C' D'] are the result of transforming [A B C D], then difference between norms of hte two should give us the "error".